# What is the best practice to keep some tables in one database synchronized in other database?

Tags: database, django, rest, synchronization, replication

I have 2 Django projects with their own databases. I want to have few models same in both databases. One app will only read those models and it cannot write new items. What is the best way to have fresh data in that app? Maybe through REST api, or database replication?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess you mean "projects" instead of "apps"? Would it be possible for both apps two have access to both databases?

Comment: yes, projects. sorry. no, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to synchronize the data fast and efficient between two databases replication is for sure the way to go... Don't know if you are using MySQL or Postgres, but for both solutions exist...

If you can access both databases from both projects you can also look into [Django's support for multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/).

If both of this options are not possible you could also try to create something like an Rest-API on one side and access it via the web. Don't know what kind of data you want to share, if you need the data for authentication you'll also find some solutions for that...

Comment: thanks. Maybe the solution can be this - one side checks every night for changes on other side, and then do that changes in own database. I just dont know what is the best way to log changes and check for them?

Comment: Well I don't know certain circumstances: How can you "connect" the databases? (same data center?)... Some more detailled description about the data you want to share? (actuality/type etc)